# large px sized comp not rendering in after effects

Tags: after-effects

19000x40 sized comp (for sports stadium) won't render in after effects. It 'looks' like it's rendering, but the resulting QT mov file is black.
What could be some of the problems here? How can I fix this?  I have a smaller version 8000px long x 40px wide that renders just fine.

I tried remaking the comp and exporting it at different length sizes. It seems that After effects is unable to export it without corrupting if it's longer than 8000px. At least on my system with this file. Strangely enough I was able to get this 19000px wide file to export earlier in the week, but not any more. So strange.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting problem.

Comment: Use the Animation codec next time...

Comment: I tried that also, it didn't work beyond 8000px wide.

Comment: Rendering to an image sequence a good way to get around problems such as this. You can then compress the image sequence to h.264 or whatever you're using for delivery. Doing an uncompressed master means that you don't have to re-render if you want to change your compression or quality settings for the final video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So really wanted to be able to export from afx `uncompressed` but could not find a codec that would allow export of such a wide pixel width. I tried 'animation', that did not work for me. If you know of another codec that does work at the larger widths, let me know!

Anyhow, I ended up just exporting with H264 codec / compression which works even with the huge pixel width. Then used an older version of Apple's Compressor to reexport that to uncompressed AVI. It looks fine.